# Odd behavior with grep -q in a bash script

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to write a small bash script that will check if each element of a sequence of numbers is in a given file, and print the ones that aren't.

find_missing.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
for num in {1..5}; do
    if ! [[ $(grep -q "$num" numbers.txt) ]]; then
        echo "$num"
    fi
done
```

numbers.txt:

```
1
2
5
```

Expected output:

```
3
4
```

Actual output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

If I change the line `grep -q "$num" numbers.txt` to `grep "$num" numbers.txt`, I get the expected output. However, my understanding is that the `-q` flag should be returning an exit code of 0 if the number is found and an exit code of 1 if it isn't found, and I don't understand why having or not having the flag makes a difference.

If I try to run individual instances of the grep command, I get the behavior I expect:

```
grep -q "1" numbers.txt; echo "$?"
0
```

```
grep -q "3" numbers.txt; echo "$?"
1
```

Can anyone help me understand what's going on here?

Comment: `$( ... )` captures the output, but `grep -q` produces no output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$( ... )` captures the output, but `grep -q` produces no output. Don't use it. You don't even need the square brackets as `if` can use the exit status:

```
if ! grep -q "$num" numbers.txt ; then
```

You can get the same output with

```
printf '%s\n' {1..5} | grep -vwFf numbers.txt -
```

Comment: What exactly is the final `-` signifying in your alternate construction?

Comment: @NathanPierson The `-` tells `grep` to search its standard input (in this case, the input from the pipe). See #13 in the [POSIX utility syntax guidelines](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02). Note that the `numbers.txt` file is not what's being searched, it's an argument to the `-f` option, meaning that its contents will be used as a list of things to search for (or rather, search for *the absence of*, because the `-v` option inverts the search).